# Does iOS11 handle viewport different?

Tags: ipad, viewport, ios11

On my iPad Mini I can only install up to iOS 9.3, the website looks fine there and on any other device. But colleagues with a new iPad and iOS 11.0.3 have the website only filling about 60% of the screen (both portrait and landscape mode).

[see iPod photo a colleague sent me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnabX.jpg)

I made the website for 100% screen width on all devices and never had a problem, worked fine the last 2 years. I would say the website code is sober, the problem comes from iOS. But since I can only check iOS 9.3 or iOS 11, I do not exactly know at which version of iOS the error exactly started.

I can not find any information whatsoever about where this may come from or other people mentioning such a problem. Does iOS11 handle viewport different?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: No, I never found anyone saying he has the same problem, the website still has a 30 or 40% white gap on the right side on all newer iOS devices. But at least one can zoom in.